# Luxon invalid date

Tags: luxon

I'm using Luxon 3.3.0 and trying to parse this date.

```
const dateStr = '09-MAY-23 01.53.41.500211 PM';

const dateTime = DateTime.fromFormat(dateStr, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a');

console.log(dateTime );
```

But I get an invalid date.
Any ideas to why that would happen?

Here is the jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/bnv7uw3t/2/

Comment: `SSSSSS` is not [a supported specifier](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens), does Luxon even support microseconds?

Comment: @orhtej2 it looks like it supports milliseconds with padding. https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=table-of-tokens

Comment: Yes, that's 3 digits (milliseconds) not 6 (microseconds). The table shows complete list of format specifiers, `SSSSSS` is not amongs them.

Comment: @orhtej2 I guess the verbiage for "padding" should be changed than, don't you think? Or at least point out the limitations of padding in this case.

Comment: @orhtej2 can you please provide that as an answer? I was able to remove the microseconds from the date and remove the extra SSS, it works now.

Comment: I'm not sure the documentation needs updating "SSS | millisecond, padded to 3" seems fairly obvious to me, although I know I have read things like this in the past and misunderstood them. It usually becomes obvious when you double check your assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your code is that `SSSSSS` is not a valid format specifier.

Upon closer inspection of [the sources](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/impl/tokenParser.js#L142) while [DateTime objects only support up to milliseconds](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/datetime.js#L120) it is possible to parse your input with `u` specifier which, contrary to [the docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens) accepts up to 9 digits (discarding part after first 3).

```
const dateStr = '09-MAY-23 01.53.41.503211 PM';
const dateTime = DateTime.fromFormat(dateStr, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.u a');
console.log(dateTime);
```

> ```
> (...snip...)
>  c: {
>     day: 9,
>     hour: 13,
>     millisecond: 503,
>     minute: 53,
>     month: 5,
>     second: 41,
>     year: 2023
>   },
> (...snip...)
> ```